# Refactoring 3 different UI components into one UIView into a CocoaPod

Tags: ios, uiview, cocoapods

in my iOS project i've been re-using the same 3 different types of UI elements:

- Label
- input
- check mark (or X ).

And the logic is the same:

- when the user is entering text, validate.
- while validation fails, red check mark,etc.

So, the next obvious stage is to refactor this into one UIView so that I can just drag and drop.

And I want this into a Cocoa pod.

Refactoring the elements into a UIview, etc is not hard. But I'm stuck on putting this logic into a Cocoa Pod. The XIB doesn't load so the subview is empty.

I've added `IB_DESIGNABLE` to the header file but still no rendering. And exception at runtime.

Suggestions? What can I post to help?

EDIT:

My resource section of the podspec

```
s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
  s.resources = 'Pod/Assets/**/*'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'jawbreaker' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

UIView doesnt load XIB file automatically. When you create an UIView class you need something like this: http://eppz.eu/blog/uiview-from-xib-simplest/ .

```
MyView *view = [Myview loadFromNib];
```

An if you want use IB_DESIGNABLE remember: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202160/846780

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `s.resource_bundle` directive, where you specify which NIBs to load.